# Level curves of two similar functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was trying to plot the level curves of f(x,y)=xy and f(x,y)=2^(xy). Algebraically, by doing f(x,y)=c I got that both are the function 1/x multiplied by a constant, once it's simply c, and once ln(c)/ln(2). However, when I plotted them with a computer (can't add images due to not enough reputation here yet), the level curves of 2^(xy) indeed looked like 1/x, but these of f(x,y)=xy, had lines also in the 2nd and 4th quadrants. You can use this site to plot and see what I am talking about: http://www.flashandmath.com/mathlets/multicalc/contours/combo.html. I don't understand why it is like this.

Answer (score 1):

The default settings of that plotter is to plot level curves $f(x,y) = c$ for $9$ equally spaced values of $c$ strictly between the minimum and the maximum of $f(x,y)$ over the region $-4 \le x,y \le 4$.

For $f(x,y) = xy$, the minimum and maximum of $f(x,y)$ over the region $-4 \le x,y \le 4$ is $-16$ and $16$ respectively. This means that the values of $c$ for which level curves are drawn are approximately $\{-12.5,-9.3,-6.2,-3,0.2,3.3,6.5,9.7,12.8\}$. This includes both positive and negative values of $c$, so there are lines drawn in the 2nd and 4th quadrants for which $f(x,y) = xy < 0$.

For $f(x,y) = 2^{xy}$, the minimum and maximum of $f(x,y)$ over the region $-4 \le x,y \le 4$ is $2^{-16} \approx 0$ and $2^{16} = 65536$ respectively. This means that the values of $c$ for which level curves are drawn are approximately $\{6553.6,13107.2,19660.8,26214.4,32768,39321.6,45875.2,52428.8,58982.4\}$. This only includes values of $c$ larger than $1$, so there are no lines drawn in the 2nd and 4th quadrants for which $f(x,y) = 2^{xy} < 2^0 = 1$.

If you want to see contours of $f(x,y) = 2^{xy}$ which are in the 2nd and 4th quadrants, try using the values like $\{0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000,10000\}$ or something else which includes values between $0$ and $1$ exclusive.